# R - Importing xlsx file with date column

Tags: r, date, time, xlsx

When I try to read in an excel file it always messes with the date/time.

```
library(openxlsx)

download.file("http://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/db_indicators/surveys/documents/series/nace2_ecfin_1801/services_subsectors_sa_nace2.zip", destfile="services_subsectors_sa_nace2.zip")

unzip("services_subsectors_sa_nace2.zip")

bcs<-read.xlsx("services_subsectors_sa_m_nace2.xlsx", colNames=TRUE, sheet="73")
```

Column 1 (no name given in the original dataset) would be the date/time column. By default this colum gets given the name 73 when it enters R.

I tried

```
as.POSIXct(bcs$73, format="%d/%m/%Y", tz="CET")
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you need the origin of the files... I checked the Excel and did some engineering and if you use `as.Date(head(bcs$`73`,50), origin="1899-11-30")` you get the first day of each named month.

Comment: I tried: but not working :P

as.POSIXct(bcs$"73", format="%d/%m/%Y", tz="CET", origin = "1985-01-31")

Comment: I guess you mean something like `format(as.POSIXlt(bcs$"73", origin = "1985-01-31"), format="%d/%m/%Y")`. In this case the numbers get interpret as seconds and the column will show `1985-01-31 09:37:58 CET`, `1985-01-31 09:37:59 CET` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`janitor`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) package, especially the function [`excel_numeric_to_date`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/blob/master/R/excel_dates.R).

Another option would be to use the package `readxl` to read your excel file which converts automatically date columns in datetime :

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("services_subsectors_sa_m_nace2.xlsx", sheet="73")
```